# My emulator shows just Listview on entire screen. even its width is limited to 240dp

Tags: android

I am using drawer layout and Listview is using as drawer.

My emulator just showing Listview as width set to match parent even it's set to 240dp.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer Layout"
    android:background="#000000">   

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawer layouts are usually hidden outside of the screen until you open them. Try opening the drawer by swiping from the side.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `NavigationView` inside `DrawerLayout` and limit width in `NavigationView`.

Example layout structure is like that , there is 2 different usage of `NavigationView` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- you can add extra views in DrawerLayout --> 
    <include layout="@layout/content_home"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/homepage_leftdrawer"/>

   <!-- you can use listview, recyclerview etc in navigationview --> 
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/homepage_right_header"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```